# ERROR : "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions" while using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, web-testing

**Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions**

This error occurred when I tried the following code:

```
<iframe src="chrome://extensions"></iframe>
```

Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's a Chrome URL. Any URLs starting with `chrome://` are automatically blocked.

Comment: So there is no bypass for it??

Comment: @ManjitPardeshi There isn't. Even if there was, you couldn't programmatically interact within the iframe and it would only work on Chrome.